# Coldfusion Builder Plugin doesn't load

Tags: eclipse, coldfusion, coldfusionbuilder

I have to say that while I love ColdFusion Builder, I hate setting it up.  Every time I have to take 4 or 5 installs before I get it right.  At the moment I am setting up CFBuilder 2016, 64 bit.  I want to set it up as a plugin on this Eclipse setup: [Eclipse IDE for JavaScript Web Developers](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-javascript-web-developers/indigosr2).

I'm using the 64-bit version of both. I extract the Eclipse environment to my desktop. Then go install CFBuilder, specify the folder I extracted to, and install.  When it completes and starts up, it runs, but none of the ColdFusion Builder add ins are available. CF is not available as a new project, CFMs aren't available as new files, etc.

Comment: Did you check your `Adobe_ColdFusion_Builder_InstallLog.log` file to see what went wrong?

Comment: No errors in the install log.  Everything was successful.

Comment: Did you run the installer with "Run as administrator" privilege?

Comment: Yes. The installer MUST run with the "Run as administrator" privilege

Answer (score 0):

Your link implies Eclipse Indigo (3.7). Though CFBuilder installation FAQ at https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/installing-coldfusion-builder.html states Eclipse 3.4.2 or higher, its actual installer insists on 4.3.2/4.4/4.5 (Kepler/Luna/Mars) [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hj8lf.jpg). As of Halloween 2016, it doesn't seem to install correctly in 4.6 (Neon) either.